# linux bash tail path=variable with spaces

Tags: string, bash, tail

Trying to fix the problem with tail, i can't avoid error when give tail a var with white spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash
.
.
.
function load_data
{
path="/home/robert/folder with_spaces/my_file"
}
.
.
.
function read_from_file
{
load_data
readed_line="$(tail -n 1 $path)"
}
```

and get error

```
tail: cannot open ‘/home/robert/folder’ for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open ‘with_spaces/my_file’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

try to add string by `$var+=$var1`
modificated var's with: `""` `''`  ``` `` ```

but still the same

---

```
bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Use quotes! `readed_line=$(tail -n 1 "$path")`. Funny, you put quotes when they are useless (yet harmless) and you don't put them when they are _mandatory_.

Comment: Big thanks,sorry for bad coded